# Did the Netziv write the Emek Davar?

Tags: commentaries, haamek-davar

Was the commentary on the Torah written by the Netziv (Ha'emek Davar) actually written by the Netziv or was it compiled from the oral shiurim that he gave in the Yeshiva?

Answer (score 5):

From the [Hakdama that the Netziv](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14024&st=&pgnum=9) wrote for the Ha'ammek Davar it is clear that the Netziv wrote this himself.

Comment: I thought that maybe the hakdama was written after his notes/shiurim were complied and brought to him.

Comment: If you read the page of the Hakdama I linked it says the Chibur that I made